# How is more than one bit read at a time?

Tags: byte

This seems like it should be incredibly easy for me to grasp, but I am going insane trying to understand it. I understand that the computer only understands on or off, so what I am trying to understand is a situation where the computer reads more than one on or off value at a time - as in byte-addressable memory - where it would need to read 8 values of on and off to get the byte value. If the computer reads these 8 values sequentially - one after the other - then that would make sense to me. But from what I gather it reads all of these on and off states at the same time. I assume this is accomplished through the circuit design? Would someone be able to either explain this in simple terms to my simple mind or direct me to a resource that could do so? I would love to not have to be committed to the mental hospital over this - thanks.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but data is normally read via a [data bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)), which comprises a number of parallel data lines (typically 8, 16, 32, 64 or even more).

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul - I didnt really know where to ask my question. I understand that data busses allow for the transfer of bits in parallel, but I still can't visualize how all 8 bit values (which are on and off values on their particular wire of the data bus) are read at the same time to form a byte?

Comment: Each line on the buss carries a single bit, hence 8 in parallel in 8-bit computers and so on.  One bit per line, enough lines in parallel to carry however many bits constitute a byte on that particular hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean reading the data off of a CD, it does happen sequentially. Each bit is gathered individually by a laser, but this operation is still treated as occurring all at once conceptually because it doesn't expose sufficiently fine-grained control to other parts of the computer to for it to be instructed to read just one bit. Simplified, the way this works is that a laser bounces off a mirror which depending on whether it is scratched or not in that particular place either causes the laser to bounce back and hit a photo-transistor (unscratched) setting a single bit to off, or to be deflected and not hit the photo-transistor (scratched), setting the bit to on. Even though it is loading these bits sequentially, it will always load complete bytes into its buffer before sending them to the computer's memory. Multiple bits travel from the hard drive buffer to memory at once. This is possible because the bus connecting them has multiple wires. Each wire can only hold one value at a given time, either high voltage or low (on or off). Eight adjacent wires can hold a byte at once.

A hard drive works by the same principal except rather than a laser and a scratched disk, you have a disk that is magnetized in specific locations, and a very sensitive inductor that will have current flow one way or another depending on the polarity of the accelerating magnetic field below it (i.e. the spinning disk).

Other parts of computer hardware actually do their operations in parallel. For sending information between different parts of the memory hierarchy, you can still think of this as just having multiple wires adjacent to each other.

Processing actually is built around the fact that multiple bits are being accessed at once, i.e. that there are different wires with on and off right next to each other. For example, in modern computers, a register can be thought of as 64 adjacent wires. (Calling them wires is a pretty big simplification at this point, but it is still gets across the appropriate idea.) A processor is built up of logic gates, and logic gates are made up of transistors. Transistors are a physical objects that have four places to attach wires. (1),(2),(3), and (4). A transistor allows current to flow from (1) to (2) if and only if the voltage at (3) is higher than the voltage at (4). Basically, a logic gate sets the voltage at (3) and (4) on a bunch of wires, and has a constant ON supply at (1), and (4) will only be powered if the amount of voltage at (3) and (4) matches the configuration that the logic gate is allowed to power.

From there it is pretty easy to see how input of some pre-specified size can be operated on at once.

If each of the gates in the drawing below is an OR gate, the drawing would show a new composite gate that calculated the OR of 8 bits at once instead of just two.

```
                   (calculated end -- registers get written to here)
       ^
   ^       ^       (everything that happens in here is "invisible" to the computer)
 ^   ^   ^   ^
a b c d e f g h    (registers get read here)
```

Processors are built with a bunch of operations of some specified depth in number of transistors so that every 2 ^ - 32 second or so, the processor can flip a switch that allows the voltage stored at the calculated end of the gates to flow back to the registers. So that it can be used in new computations or pushed over wires back to memory.

That, in a nut shell, is what it means for a computer to deal with multiple bits at once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is a byte in memory really just 8 adjacent wires read sequentially to get a byte value?

Comment: You're confusing hard disks with optical media - hard disks use electromagnetic properties to read/write data.

Comment: @PaulR You're right. I've adjusted my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @user3075144 A byte in memory is essentially 8 adjacent wires. "Reading" is transferring their data from memory to a register. Basically, eight switches connecting those "wires" to the register "wires" get flipped at once. That's what a read operation is. Then once the data is in the register, it gets operated on at once as shown in the diagram above. The "^" on the same line are gates that are physically next to each other. The ones above are physically connected to the output of the ones below. All of the gates at the bottom line operate one microsecond, the next line in the next microsecond

Comment: I'm wondering what it means for the data to be 'in the register' as you mention above- in the sense of how that is physically implemented.